# Ember actions not firing after moving to ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've begun porting my app from everything in script tags and a single .js file, to ember-cli.  My routes, models, and rendering all work, but for some reason no controller actions are firing. None. Anywhere. This app works fine until I pull everything into their own files to conform to the ember-cli directory/module structure. Any ideas what could be causing this?

The rendered DOM elements all have 'data-ember-action' on them as expected, but clicking them doesn't do anything, and neither does an explicit `click()` call using jQuery on the console.  There is no output of any kind on the console as typically happens when "action not found" errors occur, and none of my code gets hit.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely it isn't using your controllers, it's probably building up a dummy.  Your naming schema is probably not matching what ember-cli is expecting.

You could prove this fairly quickly by tossing a property in your controller

```
var IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  foo: 'bar'
});

export default IndexRoute;
```

and then referencing the property in your template

```
I'm using the controller and it's property is {{foo}}
```

You can also see this in the ember chrome extension, where it shows what type of controller is being used.

Comment: no, I've already done this test.  It's hooked up to the right controller, it's just that no actions are ever sent to it.

Comment: Bummer, we can always hope for the easy answer, would you mind posting up some code of the relevant areas?

Comment: it is an easy answer; stupidity and dumb luck.  Posting my answer now so I can forever be shamed on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

This was just massive stupidity and luck.  In my original application I initialized the Ember App like this:

```
Ember.Application.extend({
    customEvents: {
        tap: "click",
        click: null //Prevent tap from registering as two clicks
    }
});
```

Obviously this did absolutely nothing since I never store and reuse the result of that call.  In the ember-cli app:

```
var App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: 'my-app', // TODO: loaded via config
  Resolver: Resolver,
  customEvents: {
    tap: "click",
    click: null //Prevent tap from registering as two clicks
  }
});
```

This time `customEvents` actually took hold, breaking everything.

Comment: hahaha, nice find, I love when I find remnants of old code when I was learning stuff.